# fullcalendar zorder issue

Tags: fullcalendar, z-order

I have an issue with fullcalendar version v1.5.3.

This looks like it is due to the zorder of the events being rendered in the calendar.  If I display the events in a day agenda format with 15 minute slots, IE has a habit of rendering one event so that it overlaps the next one.  This renders perfectly in Firefox.

Is there a way to programmatically alter the zorder of the events are they are being rendered, so that the earliest event is always on top?